# Getting error during runtime related to file input using getline

Tags: c++, file-io, getline

This is not homework, it is self study. I am getting an unexpected error that is think is the result of getline requesting after the end of file.  I though I was checking to see if input was successful with the while(getline(inf,mystring)) but its not working. How do I effectively check for end of file if this is not the case?

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string mystring, substring1 = "", substring2 = "";
    int sos;
    ifstream inf (argv[1]);  //open file for reading
    if (!inf)
    {
        // Print an error and exit
        cerr << "Uh oh, " << argv[1] << " could not be opened for reading!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
        while(getline(inf,mystring))
        {
                sos = mystring.find_first_not_of(" ");
                if (sos != 0)
                {
                    mystring = mystring.substr(sos, string::npos);
                }
                sos = mystring.find_first_of(" ");
                if (sos != 0)
                {
                    substring1 = mystring.substr(0,sos);
                    substring2 = mystring.substr(sos + 1, string::npos);
                }
                sos = substring2.find_first_of(" ");
                if (sos != 0)
                {
                    substring2 = substring2.substr(0, sos);
                }
                cout << substring2 << " " << substring1;

        }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error

```
World Helloterminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr
```

This is the input file input.in

```
         Hello World
```

Comment: Please use a debugger and pinpoint the crash to a single line of code. That should make life easier for all of us.

Comment: Do you have empty lines in the file?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It is supposed to read in one or more lines, remove leading and trailing spaces and then swap the 2 words that are on each line.

Comment: @WilliamMichaelVondran Then I will supply better code for you.

Comment: Are there only two words on each line? And your intention is to simply print the strings in reverse order?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thank you, but my intention is to learn why it is not working as expected. Not to have someone do it for me.  I have been a VB programmer for a long time but I need to broaden my skill set to find gainful employment in other areas.  Part of my problem with C++ is that not everything easily translates over like the way file input and EOF works. This is not my homework it's my own personal learning.

Comment: @WilliamMichaelVondran I understand. I will try to help you as best as I can. But first can you tell if there are only two words on each line? And you just want to print them in reverse order, correct? :)

Comment: Yes 2 words per line and they have to be printed in reverse order.  You have to deal with empty lines and also remove leading and trailing spaces.  There may also be an unknown number of spaces between the words as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you extract a sub-string, you need to check that the range of the sub-string is physical (that is, the first index of a call to $substr$ comes before the last).  I suspect that your file contains an empty line, in this case a call to $find_first_not_of$ will return $npos$ indicating that nothing was found before the end of the string.

I would suggest adding a check for $npos$ returned from $find_first_not_of$:

```
// Strip leading spaces
sos = mystring.find_first_not_of(" ");
/* sos == 0 would mean substr(0, npos) -> useless.
   sos == npos would mean substr(npos, npos) -> un-physical. */
if (sos != 0 && sos != string::npos)
{
    mystring = mystring.substr(sos, string::npos);
}

// Split string by first space
sos = mystring.find_first_of(" ");
substring1 = mystring.substr(0, sos); /* sos != 0, since strip leading spaces */
/* Check that sos+1 is inside the string. */
if (sos+1 < mystring.length())
{
    substring2 = mystring.substr(sos+1, string::npos);
}
else
{
    substring2 = "";
}

sos = substring2.find_first_of(" ");
/* sos == 0 would cause substr(0, 0) -> un-physical,
   sos == npos would cause substr(0, npos) -> useless. */
if (sos != 0 && sos != string::npos)
{
    substring2 = substring2.substr(0, sos);
}

count << substring2 << ' ' << substring1 << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that find_first_not_of returns string::npos when it doesn't find anything - not zero as you are testing.
If you have a line with no spaces (or an empty line) then your test for find_first_not_of(" ") will return string::npos leading to

```
mystring = mystring.substr(string::npos, string::npos);
```

which will cause an exception.